# Actual memory consumption of exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a server with 2GB of RAM. Exchange 2007 requires at least 2GB of RAM. I'll also be using this as a webserver. The exchange server will only be used lightly and by a maximum of three people. Will it actually utilize the 2GB of RAM?

EDIT: It is a VPS, that is why there is such little RAM. Is there any way to limit the RAM that it consumes?

Comment: It will use as much memory as it needs. Try it in a VM?

Comment: What operating system do you have? 2 GB of RAM is crazy small for even a workstation any more, and as cheap as RAM is, it shouldn't be too hard to upgrade the RAM.

Comment: So... it's a VPS. Where is your Domain Controller exactly... this box as well per chance?

Comment: If you think that 2Gb of ram is way too much then Exchange Server 2007 is not for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way you will be able to tell how much memory it will use.

Exchange is effectively a big database, so it will try and get as much in memory as possible. That's not to say however that if your mailbox database is only 600MB it will only use 600MB of memory. Exchange has a ton of "other" services it runs apart from the information store, all of which can use varying and considerable amounts of memory.

Put Exchange aside for a moment, and Windows needs memory to run stuff, your antivirus requires memory, your backup agent will require memory. What I'm trying to say is numerous other things running on the server all require memory, and if you and I buy the exact same server, we'll install different bits and pieces on it and it will have a different memory footprint.

You can run all the calculators you want and read all the guidelines, but they're just that - **guide**lines. Personally, these days I won't get a server with less than 12GB of memory in it, because in the overall scheme of things, it is relatively cheap and if I were you, I'd try and get some more in your box.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to run Exchange for only 3 users.  That's like using a machine gun to kill mice.  You really need to look into hosted Exchange services from some other provider.  It'll make your life easier, and free up memory for any other services you want to run on your VPS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a calculator from Microsoft to Exchange that helps you to know what hardware will you need for your number of users and features that they will use.
It's avaiable here http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2007/07/05/3403332.aspx